# Getting the relevant key from ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app that is basically a table for soccer that updates every time I change it in my DB.

I'm using Firebase in this way:

[image]

I'm trying to use an `addValueEventListener`, but I don't know which one of the values is the one that changes (dif,score,points...) therefore I don't which field in my table I should update.

```
public class table extends AppCompatActivity {
Button insert;
TextView name, games, win, lost, tie, score, dif, points;
Team A;
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference FootballRef = mRootRef.child("Football");
DatabaseReference HouseARef = FootballRef.child("HouseA");


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey() ;
            Toast.makeText(table.this,key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message

            // ...
        }
    };
    HouseARef.addValueEventListener(postListener);
}
}
```

See here, when let's say I'm updating the name of `housaA`, I want to get back the key that got updated (in my case, `name`), but when I'm using
`dataSnapshot.getKey()` the Toast I'm getting back is `HouseA` and not `name`.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using a valuelistener.

Instead put a childeventlistener on the houseA.

Now inside onChildChanged, you should get the child node under houseA which has changed as a datasnapshot and from this snapshot, you can get the key which has changed

Comment: you will have to share the json tree structure if you want this answer to be more exact than this though....

Comment: glad to have helped :)